# Unidirectional OneToMany relation with JoinTable - table not generated

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-2.1

I tried to create an unidirectional OneToMany relation with a JoinTable in Play Framework 2.1. However, the framework is not generating the 'JoinTable': "transformation_input_files". The strange part is that if I change the relation to ManyToMany the table is generated. Here is the code:

So its about an Transformation class containing multiple S3Files. Here is the Transformation file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transformations")
public class Transformation extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    /*...*/

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
        name="transformation_input_files",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="transformation_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="input_file_id")
    )
    public List<S3File> inputFiles;
}
```

Here is the S3File:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="s3files")
public class S3File extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    /*...*/
}
```

The S3Files are used in more models, so that can not be a bidirectional relation. If I change @OneToMany in @ManyToMany it does generate the join table, however, I do like to stick with the @OneToMany relation.

How do I solve this problem? Did I missed something?

Comment: When there is one-to-many relationship between A and B (say), then there is no need of intermediate table. B can have AId (foreign key) as its column, and each row will have a parent A pointed by it. May be the reason?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is true, however the S3Files (which is class B in your example) is used by more classes. So say there are other classes like C and D who have a similar OneToMany relationship with B, now class B contains columns for A, C and D. If B was created and owned by a C instance, A and D are null and even unrelated.

Comment: Map the join table, the table will be autogeneratd and its considered a good practice too.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "map the join table"?

Comment: Is the jargon for hbm files, but you're using anotations (my bad...), i meant make an Entity which only contains many-to-one relationships, i know that will make them to be bidirectional relationships but i dont see how that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one-to-many relationship you have to store the relation in "Many" entity..if you don't want to store the value in the S3File class you have to create another class to join the two classes.

```
Example:
@Entity
@Table(name="transformations_ s3files")
public class Relation extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Transformation transformation;        

    @OneToOne
    public S3File file;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I look at this as a 'workaround' and I will explain why. First  I don't like the idea of making relations between entities explicit in the same way we define entities instead of using relational annotations (but I could live with that). Second this way of relations should be parsed in a proper way because the documenentation describes this relation. [Link to documentaion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1642)

Comment: Its not a work around, its pretty common to make entities for join tables, this way, your queries are more flexible when you're joining through join tables and you can add non-key extra columns when requiered.
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: Ebean doesn't support the join table in OneToMany relation.